# SQL query spot change only if over specific time

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with the format

```
user, fav_colour, date
```

with sample data:

```
a, green, 2015-10-1
a, green, 2016-10-1
a, yellow, 2016-12-1
b, red, 2015-10-1
b, red, 2016-10-1
b, red, 2017-10-1
c, black, 2014-10-1
c, black, 2015-10-1
c, blue, 2016-02-1
```

How would I run a query that returns users, where the latest `fav_colour` is different to the previous `fav_colour` and the time difference is 3 months at least

so the query would return

```
c
```

a is not included because yellow follows green only two months later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lag` window function to find each row's previous row. Note, however, that you can't use it in a `where` clause, so you'd have to use a subquery, or something equivalent:

```
SELECT username
FROM   (SELECT username,
               fav_colour,
               LAG(fav_colour) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY date) AS
                  prev_fav_colour,
               date,
               LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY date) AS
                   prev_date
        FROM   colours) c
WHERE  fav_colour != prev_fav_colour AND
       AGE(date, prev_date) >= INTERVAL '3 MONTHS';
```

Comment: What is colours here? Is this what you are calling the table?

Comment: @Abe yes - you didn't specify a table name, so I just went with something that made sense

Comment: ok thanks and what is c? is it what you are calling the subquery? Is a name necessary?

Comment: @Abe A table-alias for the inner query

Answer (score 1):

The following query uses the approach of first restricting the table to the two most recent records for each user, then checking the date difference in months between the most recent and second to most recent date.

```
SELECT
    t.user
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.user ORDER BY t.date DESC) rn
    FROM your_table t
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
GROUP BY t.user
HAVING
    MAX(t.fav_colour) <> MIN(t.fav_colour) AND   -- different colors
    AGE(MAX(t.date::date), MIN(t.date::date)) >= INTERVAL '3 MONTHS';
   -- above date calculation ensures 3 months or greater apart
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

A different method from me but hopefully gives the same answer.

1) I've made a Common Table Expression (CTE) that adds a row number to order the each users fav_colour by date ascending.

2) I've then self joined this CTE on user and row_number +1 so each record should be matched to the next record for that user.

3) Then in the WHERE clause I've the criteria of 3 months apart and a different colour

Hope this helps!

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
user, 
fav_colour, 
date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date ASC) as rn
)

SELECT 
CTE1.user
FROM CTE AS CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE AS CTE2 CTE1.user=CTE2.user ON CTE1.rn=(CTE2.rn+1)
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm,CTE1.date,CTE2.date) >=3
AND CTE1.fav_colour<>CTE2.fav_colour;
```